# Not recognising hours Mins and seconds as part of a valid date format

Tags: c#, date-conversion

Trying to parse this string into a datetime variable:

```
var test = "2018 11 24 17 3 57 345";
var format = "yyyy MM dd HH mm ss fff";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I get this error:

**System.FormatException
  HResult=0x80131537
  Message=String '2018 11 24 17 3 57 345' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider) line 28**

Comment: In your format minutes are 2 digits, in your string 1 digit.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen Ah simple as that. how embarrassing:) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var test = "2018 11 24 17 3 57 345";
var format = "yyyy MM dd HH m ss fff";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`mm` is `00`-`59`, `m` is `0`-`59`.

To support both, supply two formats:

```
var test = "2018 11 24 17 3 57 345";
var format = "yyyy MM dd HH m ss fff";
var format2 = "yyyy MM dd HH mm ss fff";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, new string[] { format, format2 }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: thanks but sometimes the minute can be a double digit

Comment: As in `05` instead of just `5`? Then pass both formats to the method and one of them will work, see my edit.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson There is a variant of Parse that takes an array of Format Strings and will match to the 1st one not throwing an Exception.